# Windows service cannot see named semaphore

Tags: c#, windows-services, semaphore

I'm trying to mediate a small windows service, making it to wait for a signal from another process during startup. For sure I know that such approach may (or even will) sometimes lead to service startup timeout. That's not the case.

The problem is with named System.Thread.Sempaphore I use for mediation purposes. Semaphore is created and acquired somewhere else using following construct. There's no change GC has it as I explicitly break the execution right below given line for test purposes.

```
Boolean newOne;
System.Threading.Semaphore rootSemaphore = 
    new System.Threading.Semaphore(1, 1, "DummyServiceSemaphore", out newOne);
```

Code above works well, obviously. Following code works well when being executed in debug mode or under console application:

```
Boolean createdNew;
System.Threading.Semaphore semaphore = 
    new System.Threading.Semaphore(1, 1, "DummyServiceSemaphore", out createdNew);
if (createdNew) 
    throw new Exception("That's not what we wanted");
```

Exactly the same code fails when being executed as a part of Windows service:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Boolean createdNew;
        System.Threading.Semaphore semaphore = 
            new System.Threading.Semaphore(1, 1, "DummyServiceSemaphore", out createdNew);
        if (createdNew) 
            throw new Exception("That's not what we wanted");

        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Dummy() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

### Why the failure?

I've been trying to use Mutex instead, however there was another issue with it - waiting application doesn't catch up when owner calls Mutex.ReleaseMutex();

---

**UPDATE**:

As per Anurag Ranjhan response I've edited semaphore creating routine as follows and the thingy now works fine:

```
Boolean newOne = false;

System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid = 
    new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(
        System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, 
        null);

System.Security.AccessControl.SemaphoreSecurity sec = 
    new System.Security.AccessControl.SemaphoreSecurity();
sec.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.SemaphoreAccessRule(
    sid,
    System.Security.AccessControl.SemaphoreRights.FullControl,
    System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

System.Threading.Semaphore rootSemaphore = 
    new Semaphore(1, 1, "Global\\DummyServiceSemaphore", out newOne, sec);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using with [Global\](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/library/aa382954.aspx) prefix

```
System.Threading.Semaphore rootSemaphore = 
new System.Threading.Semaphore(1, 1, @"Global\DummyServiceSemaphore", out newOne);
```

From the [comment section of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> If you're using a named Semaphore in Windows, the name you choose is
> governed by Kernel naming guidelines. Some of those guidelines also
> include the Kernel Object Namespaces[1](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/library/aa382954.aspx), which describes the context
> of the kernel object. By default, with Terminal Services installed,
> kernel objects like events are limited to the current Session. This is
> done so multiple sessions running in Terminal Services won't adversely
> affect one another. Kernel Object Namespaces describe using "Local",
> "Global" and "Session" prefixes to create kernel objects that can
> apply to specific namespaces and to communicate with or limit
> communication to processes of a specific scope.

Comment: I've had that same problem recently, and even with the "Global\" prefix I still had to explicitly specify the SemaphoreSecurity object as indicated in the question update above in order to make it work inside a Windows Service. That, however, did the job!

Comment: just little fix, there has to be escaped \ or @ prefix:
`"Global\\DummyServiceSemaphore"`
or
`@"Global\DummyServiceSemaphore"`