# Open an Event object created by my service from my application

Tags: windows, winapi, service

I have created a windows service. Under which I am creating a event "test". I want to use the same event object to be set/reset by my application. But I do not seem to get the Handle of the event object through my app. But  can see the Event being listed in the BaseNamed objects.

I think I need to do something with the security Attribute of the create Event.

I am creating this event in my service

CreateEvent(NULL,
            TRUE,
            FALSE,
            TEXT("Test"))

and using OpenEvent in my application.

OpenEvent( EVENT_ALL_ACCESS,
           TRUE,
           TEXT("Test"))

Please suggest what changes I would need to make, for my app to get the handle.

**update**

After Replacing `TEXT("Test") with TEXT("Global\\Test")`. Still I didn't get the Event object handle. 
Yes, now at least its recognizing the existence of the event object with the Error return(Access Denied). It was getting a Error return (the system cannot find the file specified) earlier.
As I said, I think there is some security aspect here. 
This is what I found out: As the session creates the Event in Session 0. It cannot be inherited by my application which is being created in Session 1. For that while creating the Event object, I need to specify the security attribute structure with a proper Security Dispatcher to do so. 
Could somebody tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH); 
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(psd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(psd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {0};
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = psd;
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(&sa, TRUE, FALSE, TEXT("Global\\Test"));
LocalFree(psd);
```

```
HANDLE hEvent = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, TEXT("Global\\Test"));
```

Comment: A NULL DACL (that's what you are setting here) allows full access by anyone - hardly desirable.

Comment: The alternative is to set a DACL granting access for a specific user, and then run the app as that user.

Comment: Granting only a specific user access to the event is possible, of course, but in many cases you do not know in advance which users will need access.
My main point is that by setting a NULL DACL you unnecessarily give up control of the event. Anyone can do anything with it.
Instead create the event with the default permissions and later simply add an ACE that grants SYNCHRONIZE access to "Authenticated users". That way you stay in control but processes in other sessions can wait on the event.

Comment: Perhaps, but that is a lot harder to set up for most people's needs.

Comment: Who said security is easy?

Comment: Sometimes you want it, for example when uninstalling you have to send every possible local user this event. Thats a pretty common use case.

Answer (score 5):

Service and application are likely to run in different sessions, and you need to use "Global" kernel object namespace prefix to have the object visible by both service and application.

See example and description in [Kernel object namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> The separate client session namespaces enable multiple clients to run
>   the same applications without interfering with each other. For
>   processes started under a client session, the system uses the session
>   namespace by default. However, these processes can use the global
>   namespace by prepending the "Global\" prefix to the object name. For
>   example, the following code calls CreateEvent and creates an event
>   object named CSAPP in the global namespace:
>
> `CreateEvent( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "Global\\CSAPP" );`

See also:

- [Windows service cannot see named semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945940/windows-service-cannot-see-named-semaphore/9947951#9947951)

As default event security might deny access from the application, you need to update it as soon as you created the event and you are ready to expose it.

- API: `SetSecurityDescriptorDacl` and friends.
- Code Snippet: [Configuring a DACL for full access - event semaphores in a service app](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/2006-08/msg00494.html)