# Open a JobObject created in a service from a user session process

Tags: windows, winapi, service

I have a windows service that creates a JobObject that i need to keep alive as long as the machine is turned on - the goal is to manage a few user session processes that can terminate/start at any time with this JobObject. I am creating it in a service to make sure the process is running at startup, and that it can't be killed by regular users.

However, i don't seem to be able to open a handle to this JobObject from the user session, I always get an access denied (5) error, despite going as far as creating it with a NULL DACL.

I have found a somewhat related question here: [Open an Event object created by my service from my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890783/open-an-event-object-created-by-my-service-from-my-application), but for me, even with the NULL DACL, when asking for a JOB_OBJECT_ASSIGN_PROCESS right, i get access denied (asking for SYNCHRONIZE works for example).

The service code:

```
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(psd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(psd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr= {0};
secAttr.nLength = sizeof(secAttr);
secAttr.bInheritHandle = false;
secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = psd;

hJobObject = CreateJobObject(&secAttr, SCL_JOBOBJECTNAME);
LocalFree(psd);
```

The user session code:

```
hJobObject = OpenJobObject(JOB_OBJECT_ASSIGN_PROCESS, FALSE, SCL_JOBOBJECTNAME);
if (hJobObject == NULL)
{
    DWORD wError = GetLastError();
    printf("Error: %d\n", wError); // this always pops 5
    return 1;
}
```

Any ideas? As a test, i tried spawning a user session process from within the service, and assign the JobObject via the service code, and that worked,.. so i'm fairly certain its related to security settings i am missing, despite the NULL DACL.

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to open a job object from a different session? Why would you need to do that anyway?

Comment: Other kernel objects can be used like this, I didn't find any documentation suggesting otherwise for JobObjects. Maybe there is a better way of doing this, but i need to keep processes that are independently started throughout the user session over several days / weeks within the same JobObject to ensure they never go over a certain RAM usage. If i create the JobObject in the user session itself, I can't ensure that it starts before the first 'managed' process is fired up. A service seemed like the tool for this. Do you have any suggestions on how to approach it differently?

Comment: And you created it in the global name space? Don't you need to be running elevated to gain access to an object in the global namespace?

Comment: i think you forget set Label in your job object and it have by default `SECURITY_MANDATORY_SYSTEM_RID` when you need set to `SECURITY_MANDATORY_MEDIUM_RID` or low

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, `#define SCL_JOBOBJECTNAME L"Global\\MyJobObject"`, otherwise i get a "not found" (2) error as expected. So it seems that it finds it, but for some reason denies access with any access right that may need to modify something. So JOB_OBJECT_SET_ATTRIBUTES would fail (access denied), but JOB_OBJECT_QUERY would give me a handle for example.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan re: Global namespace, i don't think elevated rights are needed, but maybe that's my problem. If i create the entity in the global namespace in the user session, it works fine. Also, the user i am testing with is an admin user. I'll do some testing though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Certainly for some objects you don't need to elevate, so long as you secure correctly. But I don't think you are securing correctly.

Comment: global namespace not need elevated rights

Comment: i'll look into the SACL / SECURITY_MANDATORY_SYSTEM_RID settings, i need to read up on that a bit, thanks for the tip!  @DavidHeffernan yep, security is not implemented yet, as i can't even get it working with full access at this point. Once i get it working, i'll restrict to authorized users only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you create Job in service - this object by default will be have `WinSystemLabelSid` label `SID: S-1-16-16384` - *System Mandatory Level*. (i just check this) so you need not only set *Dacl* but *Sacl* too. for example:

```
    ULONG cb = MAX_SID_SIZE;
    PSID LowLabelSid = (PSID)alloca(MAX_SID_SIZE);
    if (CreateWellKnownSid(WinLowLabelSid, 0, LowLabelSid, &cb))
    {
        PACL Sacl = (PACL)alloca(cb += sizeof(ACL) + sizeof(ACE_HEADER) + sizeof(ACCESS_MASK));
        InitializeAcl(Sacl, cb, ACL_REVISION);
        if (AddMandatoryAce(Sacl, ACL_REVISION, 0, 0, LowLabelSid))
        {
            SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
            InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
            SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
            SetSecurityDescriptorSacl(&sd, TRUE, Sacl, FALSE);

            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa= { sizeof(sa), &sd, FALSE };

            if (HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObject(&sa, L"Global\\{58BFC6DB-BE93-4cdb-919C-4C713ACB5A32}"))
            {
                CloseHandle(hJob);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works great! Yep indeed, the SACL was set to SYSTEM level.

Comment: @LaszloSebo - interesting that this not for all objects. for `Job` objects by default label set to `System Mandatory Level` when for example if you create `Event` object - it will be not Mandatory Label - so by default - medium label